# What is the industry standard for automatically scaling persistent volume claims in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

How can I resize a persistent volume claim when the utilization is more than 80%?

I have never used such a solution before but now I am looking for some options. Internet shows two options as per my research.

1. Kubernetes Volume Autoscaler (https://github.com/DevOps-Nirvana/Kubernetes-Volume-Autoscaler)
2. Autopilot (https://docs.portworx.com/operations/operate-kubernetes/autopilot/use-cases/autogrow-pvc/)
3. https://github.com/redhat-cop/volume-expander-operator

Given:

1. Storage class and necessary drivers(IBM flash drive) are installed.
2. Auto exansiton is set to true.
3. Manually increasing the PVC storage request is working

What is the best or reliable way of automatically grow the pvcs?
Does the mentioned solutions widely accepted and industry standard?
Is there anything else which is better performaing technology compared to the above options.